# TelerikRadMenu from horizontal position to vertical

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am using TelerikRadMenu in asp.net but i don't want it in horizontal mode i want it in vertical...is it possible and how can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified which versions of their controls you are using `ASP.NET`, `ASP.NET AJAX` or `ASP.NET MVC`

In any case, for `ASP.NET` I think you just need to set the Flow direction to Vertical:

```
<Telerik:radMenu id="radMenu" runat="server" Flow="Vertical">
</Telerik:radMenu>
```

Comment: To add to this answer, if you're adding the Flow programmatically you don't use a string for Flow. Instead there's an enum: ItemFlow.Vertical